# How could you scientifically explain a Mage's ability to absorb energy from the environment in order to aid in casting spells?

Tags: science-based, biology, magic, super-powers

Remember these questions: [Would "magic" still be called "magic" in a modern era?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/67918/would-magic-still-be-called-magic-in-a-modern-era) and [What is the best way to introduce Superpowers into a world that previously never had them... WITHOUT destabilizing society](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/68133/what-is-the-best-way-to-introduce-superpowers-into-a-world-that-previously-never?noredirect=1&lq=1)? Well I have another question regarding these two.

How could I explain a Mage's (or Superhumans) ability to draw energy from the environment In order to cast a spell (or use their powers). For example... Let's say our Mage/Superhuman wants to shoot a baseball sized fireball from their hands, however they don't have enough metabolic energy to cast the spell...

So what they do is that they draw the remaining amount of energy from the environment (the more power you draw from the environment the more your body is damaged and your mind is strained).

So my question is... Is it possible for a magician/superhuman to draw the remaining amount of energy from the environment?

Comment: NOTE: we are using the Magic/Superpower system from the links listed within the question

Comment: I am not sure if a question about magic and superheroes should be tagged "hard-science". Especially i am not sure about the combination of the tags "magic" and "hard-science". But here is a similar question about one aspect of magic: [Darken the sky by using magic](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/53299/darken-the-sky-by-using-magic)

Comment: changed them....

Comment: "Is it possible due to magic?" is always "yes", because of Sanderson's first law: An author's ability to solve conflict with magic is DIRECTLY PROPORTIONAL to how well the reader understands said magic. "How can I explain this that involves magic?" - the answer is "more magic."

Comment: I don't like leaving my readers (not like I have any) in the dark (plot wise I can care less. But when it comes to the worldbuilding I want to know much as possible (In this case, The magic system).

Comment: And yes. I have heard (& read) Sanderson's laws. Pretty good for An Aspiring Author (get the pun?)

Comment: @Aify Regarding Sanderson's law; that is certainly not ironclad. Sanderson is writing in an age of reason; people like explanations for things. Even superhero movies feel the need to explain things with reasons other than magic. But at the the same time, the grand-daddies of fantasy, specifically Tolkien and Robert Howard, never made any effort to explain their magic. It was just something wonderful and mysterious that happened. Of course the caveat is that magic is not commonplace, and is instead restricted to very few characters in both of their worlds. Mystery can be its own system.

Comment: You could have a look at the Warhammer 40K milieu. In that legendarium, the Warp is a parallel dimension of energy, into which some humans can tap. You may or may not want to include the malignant entities, mutations, and risk of insanity that comes with this.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are referencing a magic-system with "nodes" scattered throughout the human body to use the energy of the human body an easy way to use energy outside of the human body would be to use "nodes" in the environment surrounding the "mage". Maybe you could restrict this by saying the human nodes can only reach as far as a few meters and different objects contain different amounts of nodes with different amounts of energy.